# Java ME out of memory

Tags: memory-management, java-me

I'm making a Java ME application for Symbian S60 5th edition and I have problem with the memory. After some time of running the app I recieve the out of memory exception.
I'm getting images from Google Maps (by the integrated GPS in Nokia 5800) and showing them.

I have this implemented like this:

- class `MIDlet` with method `setForm()`
- class `Data` which has a thread that collects info about the coordinates, gets image from Google maps, creates new form, appends the image, and calls the method `setForm(f)` from the `Midlet`.

Probable the `Display.setCurrent(Form f)` keeps references on the forms and like this the memory gets fast full.
I tried with `Canvas` but it has some stupid UI (some circle and some 4 buttons) that I don't like.

How can I solve this problem?

PS: the code...

1. In class `MIDlet`

   ```
   public void setInfo(Form f)
   {
       getDisplay().setCurrent(f);
   }
   ```
2. in class `TouristData` which collects information about location and gets map image

   ```
   private attributes:
       private Form f=null;
       private ImageItem imageItem=null;
       private Image img = null;
   ```
3. method `locationUpdated` which is called when recieve new location:

   ```
   public void locationUpdated(LocationProvider provider,final Location location)
   {
       if (!firstLocationUpdate)
       {
           firstLocationUpdate = true;
           statusListener.firstLocationUpdateEvent();
       }

       if(touristUI != null)
       {
           new Thread()
           {
               public void run()
               {
                   if(location != null && location.isValid())
                   {
                       //lokacija je, prikaži!
                       try
                       {
                           QualifiedCoordinates coord =location.getQualifiedCoordinates();
                           if(imageItem == null)
                           {
                               imageItem = new ImageItem(null,null,0,null);
                               imageItem.setAltText("ni povezave");
                               f.append(imageItem);
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               img =  googleConnector.retrieveStaticImage2(360,470, coord.getLatitude(), coord.getLongitude(), 16, "png32"); //z markerje
                               imageItem.setImage(img);
                           }
                       }catch(Exception e)
                       {}
                   }
                   else
                   {
                   }
               }
           }.start();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I had similar problem, my sw was running on Palm T3, so what I concluded, I could prolonge life of app by being aggresive with letting resources, all not needed variables =null all vector.clear() when not needed... VM was IBM J9 which was not something serious at all, yet it functioned somehow.

Comment: The problem is solved. I found that its possible the virtual keypad on Canvas so I used canvas, and I also put all the references on the mapImage=null. So now its everything ok with the memory.

Thanks to everybody for the help,
Milan Dojčinovski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you keeping references to the forms or the images? These will keep them from being garbage collected and will cause out of memory errors.

It is hard to tell without some source code. Anyway, it will be better to re-architect your Midlet not to create new forms, but to reuse the same one.